# Plot lines in matplotlib based on discrete discriminator

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have 4 years of seasonal data I want to plot on one graph using matplotlib.
My data is in a pandas dataframe and looks like this:

```
Total Year Day
5  2017  10/29
4  2016  10/30
3  2018  10/31
5  2019  10/31
10 2017  10/31
```

The `'Year'` and `'Day'` columns are type `str`. The `'Total'` column is type `int`.
I want the graph to have 4 lines: one line for each year. I want `'Total'` on the Y axis and `'Day'` on the X axis. I know how to do this in R using GGplot, but I can't figure it out using MatPlotLib in Python.

Comment: `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Year.astype(str) + '-' + df.Day, format='%Y-%m/%d')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to create a `'Date'` column:

```
df['Month'] = df['Day'].apply(lambda x: x.split('/')[0])
df['Day'] = df['Day'].apply(lambda x: x.split('/')[1])
df['Date'] = '2020' + '-' + df['Month'] + '-' + df['Day']
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Notice one important fact: you want *different* year to be plotted along the same x axis. In order to achieve this result, I need to report data from different years on the same *reference year*. As *reference year* I chose `2020` since it is a leap year (so it contains all possible dates, `Feb 29` included). So the `'Date'` column will contain the exact day and month, but `2020` as year, for each dataframe row.
This is required only for plotting purpose. Then you can mask the year value along x axis with proper formatting x ticks.
Finally you can loop over year and plot your data:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for year in df['Year'].unique():
    filt = df['Year'] == year
    ax.plot(df[filt]['Date'], df[filt]['Total'], label = year)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.DayLocator(interval = 15))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%m/%d'))
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation = 90)

ax.legend(frameon = True)
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Total')

plt.show()
```

### Complete code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md


df = pd.read_csv(r'data\data.csv')

df['Month'] = df['Day'].apply(lambda x: x.split('/')[0])
df['Day'] = df['Day'].apply(lambda x: x.split('/')[1])
df['Date'] = '2020' + '-' + df['Month'] + '-' + df['Day']
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for year in df['Year'].unique():
    filt = df['Year'] == year
    ax.plot(df[filt]['Date'], df[filt]['Total'], label = year)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.DayLocator(interval = 15))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%m/%d'))
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation = 90)

ax.legend(frameon = True)
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Total')

plt.show()
```

[image]